# Python group by array a, and summarize array b - Performance

Tags: python, performance, sorting, numpy, group-by

Given two unordered arrays of same lengths a and b:

```
a = [7,3,5,7,5,7]
b = [0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.1,0.2]
```

I'd like to group by the elements in a:

```
aResult = [7,3,5]
```

summing over the elements in b (Example used to summarize a probability density function):

```
bResult = [0.2 + 0.1 + 0.2, 0.1, 0.3 + 0.1] = [0.5, 0.1, 0.4]
```

Alternatively, random a and b in python:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(1,10,10000)
b = np.array([1./len(a)]*len(a))
```

I have two approaches, which for sure are far from the lower performance boundary.
Approach 1 (at least nice and short): Time: 0.769315958023

```
def approach_2(a,b):
    bResult = [sum(b[i == a]) for i in np.unique(a)]
    aResult = np.unique(a)
```

Approach 2 (numpy.groupby, horribly slow) Time: 4.65299129486

```
def approach_2(a,b): 
    tmp = [(a[i],b[i]) for i in range(len(a))]
    tmp2 = np.array(tmp, dtype = [('a', float),('b', float)])
    tmp2 = np.sort(tmp2, order='a') 

    bResult = []
    aResult = []
    for key, group in groupby(tmp2, lambda x: x[0]):
        aResult.append(key)
        bResult.append(sum([i[1] for i in group]))
```

Update: Approach3, by Pablo. Time: 1.0265750885

```
def approach_Pablo(a,b):    

    pdf = defaultdict(int); 
    for x,y in zip(a,b):
        pdf[x] += y
```

Update: Approach 4, by Unutbu. Time: 0.184849023819 [WINNER SO FAR, but a as integer only]

```
def unique_Unutbu(a,b):

    x=np.bincount(a,weights=b)
    aResult = np.unique(a)
    bResult = x[aResult]
```

Maybe someone finds a smarter solution to this problem than me :)

Comment: I meant that you cannot assume that list a is sorted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `a` is composed of ints < 2**31-1 (that is, if `a` has values that can fit in dtype `int32`), then you could use `np.bincount` with weights:

```
import numpy as np
a = [7,3,5,7,5,7]
b = [0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.1,0.2]

x=np.bincount(a,weights=b)
print(x)
# [ 0.   0.   0.   0.1  0.   0.4  0.   0.5]

print(x[[7,3,5]])
# [ 0.5  0.1  0.4]
```

`np.unique(a)` returns `[3 5 7]`, so the result appears in a different order:

```
print(x[np.unique(a)])
# [ 0.1  0.4  0.5]
```

One potential problem with using `np.bincount` is that it returns an array whose length is equal to the maximum value in `a`. If `a` contains even one element with value near 2**31-1, then `bincount` would have to allocate an  array of size `8*(2**31-1)` bytes (or 16GiB).

So `np.bincount` might be the fastest solution for arrays `a` which have big length, but not big values. For arrays `a` which have small length (and big or small values), using a `collections.defaultdict` would probably be faster.

Edit: See [J.F. Sebastian's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538382/python-group-by-array-a-and-summarize-array-b-performance/7539307#7539307) for a way around the integer-values-only restriction and big-values problem.

Comment: [Measurements](https://gist.github.com/da57326584a3811652aa#file_measurements.org) show `np.bincount()` performs well even against [Cython-based solutions](https://gist.github.com/da57326584a3811652aa#file_pdf.pyx).

Answer (score 6):

Here's approach similar to [@unutbu's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538382/python-group-by-array-a-and-summarize-array-b-performance/7539008#7539008):

```
import numpy as np

def f(a, b):
    result_a, inv_ndx = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
    result_b = np.bincount(inv_ndx, weights=b)
    return result_a, result_b
```

It allows non-integer type for `a` array. It allows large values in `a` array. It returns `a` elements in a sorted order. If it is desirable it easy to restore original order using`return_index` argument of `np.unique()` function.

It performance worsens as the number of unique elements in `a` rises. It 4 times slower than @unutbu's version on the data from your question.

I've made [performance comparison](https://gist.github.com/da57326584a3811652aa#file_measurements.org) with additional three methods. The leaders are: for integer arrays -- [hash-based implementation](https://gist.github.com/da57326584a3811652aa#file_pdf_hash.pyx) in Cython; for `double` arrays (for input size 10000) -- [sort-based  impl.](https://gist.github.com/da57326584a3811652aa#file_pdf.pyx) also in Cython.

Answer (score 2):

How about this approach:

```
from collections import defaultdict
pdf = defaultdict(int)
a = [7,3,5,7,5,7]
b = [0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.1,0.2]
for x,y in zip(a,b):
  pdf[x] += y
```

You only iterate over each element once and use a dictionary for fast lookup. If you really want two separate arrays as results in the end you can ask for them:

```
aResult = pdf.keys()
bResult = pdf.values()
```

Comment: You can use defaultdict(int), it's cleaner.

Comment: I like the approach, it is pretty. Unfortunately, it seems to be slower than 'approach 1' especially for long arrays...

Comment: @Helga: I've rewritten Pablo's implementation in Cython using [`unordered_map`](https://gist.github.com/da57326584a3811652aa#file_pdf_hash.pyx). It ~10-30 times faster.