# How to select all locations of unique elements in numpy 2d array with bounding box around them?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array I want to find the 'every' location of all the unique elements. We can find the unique elements using `numpy.unique(numpyarray.)`. Here it comes the tricky part. Now I have to know all the locations for every unique element. Lets consider the following example.

```
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],\
       [1, 1, 2, 2],\
       [3, 3, 4, 4],\
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```

The result should be

```
1, (0,0),(1,1)
2, (0,2),(1,2)
3, (2,0),(3,1)
4, (2,2),(3,3)
```

How to do it and what could be a suitable way to store and iterate over the values.

It is to be noted that all the unique values will be adjacent to each other. The only gaps between them could only be zeros. Lets consider another variant

```
 array([[1, 0, 1, 2, 2],\
        [1, 0, 1, 2, 2],\
        [3, 0, 3, 4, 4],\
        [3, 0, 3, 4, 4]])
```

The result should be

```
1, (0,0),(1,2)
2, (0,3),(1,4)
3, (2,0),(3,2)
4, (2,3),(3,4)
```

The zeoros on the boundaries are to be neglected.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple, brute force way to do it is to just use `numpy.where`.

For example, if you're just wanting the *bounding box*:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,1,2,2],
              [1,1,2,2],
              [3,3,4,4],
              [3,3,4,4]])

for val in np.unique(x):
    rows, cols = np.where(x == val)
    rowstart, rowstop = np.min(rows), np.max(rows)
    colstart, colstop = np.min(cols), np.max(cols)
    print val, (rowstart, colstart), (rowstop, colstop)
```

This will work for the example with zeros, as well.

If the array is large, and you already have `scipy` around, you might consider using `scipy.ndimage.find_objects` instead, as @unutbu suggested.

In the particular case of your example, where your unique values are sequential integers, you can use `find_objects` directly.  It expects an array where each sequential integer other than 0 represents an object that it needs to return the bounding box of. (0 is ignored, exactly as you want.) However, in general, you'll need to do a touch of pre-processing to convert arbitrary unique values to sequential integers.

`find_objects` retuns a list of tuples of `slice` objects.  Honestly, these are probably exactly what you want, if you're wanting the bouding box.  However, it will look a bit more messy to print out starting and stopping indicies.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage

x = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 2, 2],
              [1, 0, 1, 2, 2],
              [3, 0, 3, 4, 4],
              [3, 0, 3, 4, 4]])

for i, item in enumerate(ndimage.find_objects(x), start=1):
    print i, item
```

This will look slightly different than you might expect. These are `slice` objects, so the "max" value will always be one higher than the "max" in the previous example. This is so that you can simply slice with the given tuple to get the data in question.

E.g.

```
for i, item in enumerate(ndimage.find_objects(x), start=1):
    print i, ':'
    print x[item], '\n'
```

If you really want the starts and stops, just do something like this:

```
    for i, (rowslice, colslice) in enumerate(ndimage.find_objects(x), start=1):
        print i, 
        print (rowslice.start, rowslice.stop - 1),
        print (colslice.start, colslice.stop - 1)
```

If your unique values are not sequential integers, you'll need to do a bit of pre-processing, as I mentioned before. You might do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage

x = np.array([[1.1, 0.0, 1.1, 0.9, 0.9],
              [1.1, 0.0, 1.1, 0.9, 0.9],
              [3.3, 0.0, 3.3, 4.4, 4.4],
              [3.3, 0.0, 3.3, 4.4, 4.4]])
ignored_val = 0.0
labels = np.zeros(data.shape, dtype=np.int)

i = 1
for val in np.unique(x):
    if val != ignored_val:
        labels[x == val] = i
        i += 1

# Now we can use the "labels" array as input to find_objects
for i, item in enumerate(ndimage.find_objects(labels), start=1):
    print i, ':'
    print x[item], '\n'
```

Comment: Ignoring the zeros for the moment, is there a way to do this using `ndimage.find_objects`?

Comment: Absolutely!  I should have included it in the first place. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating how to do it. You make it look all so simple. By the way, I think newer versions of numpy have `np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)` which [judging from this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538382/python-group-by-array-a-and-summarize-array-b-performance/7539307#7539307) should allow you to generate `labels` without the for-loop.

Comment: Is it easy to get the 'trimmed' boundary of the objects returned by find_objects?  For example, I don't necessarily want the 'bounding box.'  I want the true coordinates of the object, i.e. the outline of each object.

Comment: @durden2.0 - There are several different libraries that implement it, but nothing directly built into `scipy`.  Have a look at `skimage.measure.find_contours`, e.g. http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_contours.html  (Note that they're plotted there, similar to `matplotlib.pyplot.contour`, but the function is just returning an array of coordinates.)  GDAL also has methods for this and it's handy if you're working with GIS data. It's overkill if you're not, though.  I think `mahotas` might also implement a similar function, as well.

Comment: Also, I forgot to say it, but the typical approach is to use a generic contour finding algorithm and contour a value of 0.5 (assuming 0-->False, 1-->True).  If you need closed polygons, you need to jump through a couple of extra hoops, but nothing too involved.

Comment: @JoeKington Thanks for the help! I'm looking for closed polygons.  I'm segmenting a 3d array into 'regions' and want to know the 'outline' of each region.  So, I'll do some looking around at your links.

Comment: @durden2.0 - If you're wanting 3D isosurfaces (i.e. the enclosing envelope of the region) have a look at `mayavi`/`tvtk`.  (`tvtk` is just a nicer wrapper for VTK that allows seamless interactions between VTK objects and numpy arrays.) The libraries I mentioned are all 2D.  However, you can use `mayavi` to create an isosurface and extract the triangulated surface.  Hope it helps!

Comment: @JoeKington I'll look into vtk, trying to not introduce more dependencies into project. I wonder if there's a way to use `generate_binary_structure` to label my array with only contiguous sections, then use `find_objects` to get the bounding boxes, and finally iterate through those slices and somehow 'mask' out the 'inner' cells to leave me with just the bounding/outline of the contiguous region.  I'm just spitballing here...

Comment: @durden2.0 - Absolutely! In fact, for filling the "inner" holes, you can just use `scipy.ndimage.binary_fill_holes`.  The harder part is going from the "raster" (e.g. gridded 2D boolean array) form to the "vector" (e.g. list of verticies) form, which is were the other libraries come in.  However, if you want to implement that part from scratch, search for "marching squares". It'll be slow in pure python (and hard to vectorize with numpy) but it's not too hard to write.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54141/discussion-between-durden2-0-and-joe-kington).