# Why is using a Cython list faster than using a Python list?

Tags: python, performance, list, numpy, cython

Here's my Python code:

```
X = [[0] * 1000] * 100
start = time()
for x in xrange(100):
    for i in xrange(len(X)):
        for j in xrange(len(X[i])):
            X[i][j] += 1
print  time() - start
```

My Cython code is the same:

```
X = [[0] * 1000] * 100
start = time()
for x in xrange(100):
    for i in xrange(len(X)):
        for j in xrange(len(X[i])):
            X[i][j] += 1
print  time() - start
```

Output:

- Python cost: 2.86 sec
- Cython cost: 0.41 sec

<s>Any other **faster way** to do the same above in Python or Cython?</s>

**Update: Any way to create an 2d array X with height indexing performance close to array int X[][] that in C/C++?**

For now I am considering use Python C API to do the job.

One more thing, a numpy array does the same thing but so much slower(70 sec) than list in both pure Python and Cython.

Python:

```
X = np.zeros((100,1000),dtype=np.int32)
start = time()
for x in xrange(100):
    for i in xrange(len(X)):
        for j in xrange(len(X[i])):
            X[i][j]+=1
```

If doing a lot of access to numeric array, which approach is the best?

Comment: Can you show the code with `numpy`?

Comment: A previous question regarding why it's faster and the price to pay for speed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697275/cython-speed-boost-vs-usability for interest

Comment: @kroolik added the numpy array code

Comment: Also another interesting related question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799977/numpy-vs-cython-speed?rq=1

Comment: numpy can be very fast if used as intended, i.e. by writing *vectorized* code. Your numpy example could be written simply as `Z = np.zeros((100, 1000), np.int32); X += 1` (or even more trivially, as `np.ones((100, 1000), np.int32)`), which should be pretty damn fast (~85us for the inplace addition on my machine). If you post the actual function you're trying to optimize then there's a good chance we could help you to write a vectorized version.

Comment: @ali_m, I had tried the np.array, but it not faster. I have posted the code here. the sample_topic function is the function i ma trying to optimize. https://github.com/darlinglele/lda_topic_model/blob/master/topic_model.py

Comment: I'm not surprised - literally none of that code is vectorized! It's not the array container itself that's any faster (accessing individual elements is actually slower than with a list), but rather it lets you apply operations to multiple array elements at once, allowing you to avoid looping over the elements in Python. To get the most out of numpy you really have to stop treating arrays like nested lists and get your head around the concept of vectorized operations ([see here for a tutorial](http://www.sam.math.ethz.ch/~raoulb/teaching/PythonTutorial/intro_numpy.html#operation-on-arrays)).

Comment: @ali_m, yes, there is no operations between arrays. I just need raw array that support quick index.

Comment: I think almost all of that code could be vectorized. Try taking your example to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) if you need advice on how to do so.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question in your title, your Cython code beats your Python code because, despite the lack of `cdef` to declare variables, C code is being generated for the `for` loops (in addition to lots of extra C code to describe the Python objects). To speed up your Cython code use `cdef` to declare the integers `i`, `j` and `x` so they're no longer Python integers: e.g. `cdef int i`. You can also [declare C-type arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528691/idiomatic-way-to-do-list-dict-in-cython) in Cython which should improve performance further.

A quick way to get the same result with NumPy:

```
X = np.zeros((100, 1000), dtype=np.int32)
X += 10000
```

If you can help it, you should never use `for` loops with NumPy arrays. They are completely different to lists in terms of memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

> Any other faster way to do the same above in Python or Cython?

The equivalent, faster code would be:

```
X = [[100 * 100] * 1000] * 100
```

In your code, you are creating a `1000`-long list of zeroes, then creating a `100`-long list of *references* to that list. Now, iterating `100` times over that `100`-long list results in each position being incremented `100 * 100 = 10000` times.

```
len(set(map(id, X)))
1
```

If you would like to end up with a list of `100` lists:

```
base = [100] * 1000
X = [list(base) for _ in xrange(100)]
len(set(map(id, X)))
100
```

Note that references to objects inside lists are *still* copied.

Comment: Thank you kroolik, your code is exact right. It's my fault that  didn't described my thought clear. I want to find a fast way to use 2d array with hight performance.like int a[][] in C code.

Comment: @lessisawesome, for what purpose? The most generic one is the one you've posted - double loop with the code you need in the inner loop, in Cython. Any more optimizations can be done with a specific use-case in mind.

Answer (score 0):

ajcr's answer probably is the fastest and simpliest one. You should first explicitly declare the datatype of your variables in the cython code. In addition I would make a `prange` instead of a simple `range` iterator for the outer loop. This will activate OpenMP multithreading what might speed up your code further but I really doubt that this solution will beat the numpy implementation.